# Babel ES6 Array destructuring

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying to compile JS using Babel with ES2015 preset.

For the below code

```
const arr = [1,2];
[x,y] = arr;
```

The babel compiles to

```
"use strict";

function _slicedToArray(arr, i) { return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _unsupportedIterableToArray(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest(); }

function _nonIterableRest() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method."); }

function _unsupportedIterableToArray(o, minLen) { if (!o) return; if (typeof o === "string") return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); var n = Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8, -1); if (n === "Object" && o.constructor) n = o.constructor.name; if (n === "Map" || n === "Set") return Array.from(n); if (n === "Arguments" || /^(?:Ui|I)nt(?:8|16|32)(?:Clamped)?Array$/.test(n)) return _arrayLikeToArray(o, minLen); }

function _arrayLikeToArray(arr, len) { if (len == null || len > arr.length) len = arr.length; for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(len); i < len; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; }

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { if (typeof Symbol === "undefined" || !(Symbol.iterator in Object(arr))) return; var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr; }

var arr = [1, 2];
var _arr = arr;

var _arr2 = _slicedToArray(_arr, 2);

x = _arr2[0];
y = _arr2[1];
_arr;
```

However for the below code

`[x,y] = [1,2];`

The babel compiles to

```
"use strict";

var _ref = [1, 2];
x = _ref[0];
y = _ref[1];
_ref;
```

Any thoughts why Babel would complicate simple stuff in the first case.

My thoughts are its a JS limitation as we can't predict return type OR Babel being ultra conscious of JS evolution

Comment: It should be `const [x,y] = arr;`?

Comment: adding a 'const' made a difference in babel. I am not sure what is going on. the JS code is legit without const keyword as well

Comment: If those variable aren't defined before that statement it may cause that kind of weirdness.